# SQL Server: Min and Max Start Dates and End dates

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how I can condense a table down into a simple table of min and max start/end dates when the variables are the same.

So imagine the results of my query creates a temp table like this as a quick example. The actual result set is like 10,000 rows long.

```
ID    Start Date  End Date   Var1   Var2  
-----------------------------------------
01    201201      201404     D      V     
01    201405      201502     D      V     
01    201503      999912     G      V     
02    201301      201412     S      T     
02    201501      999912     S      T
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that when var 1 and var 2 are the same, taking the start date and end date min and max so that the results becomes

```
ID    Start Date  End Date   Var1   Var2  
----------------------------------------
01    201201      201502     D      V     
01    201503      999912     G      V      
02    201301      999912     S      T
```

Really appreciate anyone's help or guidance.

Edit:  Forgot to mention there could be breaks.

Comment: Can you use aggregate functionas and a Group By? `Select ID,Min(StartDate), Max(EndDate), Var1, Var2 From Table Group By ID,Var1,Var2`

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post your query.

Comment: What do breaks have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
declare @t table 
(
 ID char(2)   
,[Start Date] int
,[End Date] int   
,Var1   char(1)
,Var2  char(1)
)

insert @t Values('01',    '201201',      '201404',     'D',      'V')     
insert @t Values('01',    '201405',      '201502',     'D',      'V')     
insert @t Values('01',    '201503',      '999912',     'G',      'V')     
insert @t Values('02',    '201301',      '201412',     'S',      'T')     
insert @t Values('02',    '201501',      '999912',     'S',      'T')     


Select ID , min([Start Date]) [Start Date] , max([End Date] ) , var1, var2
from @t
group by ID, var1, var2
```